# Mode of density function using optimize

Tags: r, optimization

I want to find the mode (x-value) of a univariate density function using R
s optimize function

I.e. For a standard normal function f(x) ~ N(3, 1) the mode should be the mean i.e. x=3.

I tried the following:

```
# Define the function
g    <- function(x) dnorm(x = x, mean = 3, sd = 1)
Dvec <- c(-1000, 1000)                            

# First get the gradient of the function
gradfun <- function(x){grad(g, x)}

# Find the maximum value
x_mode <- optimize(f=g,interval = Dvec, maximum=TRUE)
x_mode
```

This gives the incorrect value of the mode as:

```
$maximum
[1] 999.9999

$objective
[1] 0
```

Which is incorrect i.e. gives the max value of the (-1000, 1000) interval as opposed to x=3.

Could anyone please help edit the optimisation code.

It will be used to pass more generic functions of x if this simple test case works

Comment: the interval is too broad, with a `optimize(f=g, interval=c(-100,100), maximum=T)` you get the desired result. But with `optimize(f=g, interval=c(-200,200), maximum=T)` it seems the original seed is taken so that `g` worths `0` and still it remains very far from the maximum. The optimization hence remains stuck in the 0 value area.

Comment: Thanks @ColonelBeauvel, could you please explain how to set the seed value automatically for broad intervals? Also is there a better way to use the gradient of the function to improve this process? It is calculated above in the variable gradfun

Comment: I am open to using packages other than optimize e.g. optim will be fine if anyone can point out how to achieve the mode.

Comment: Here is an approach below. You can also mention the gradient. Remind it's doing a minimisation, hence the minus sign in front of `g`. You can mention the gradient also, beware to add a minus sign as well since you are looking for maximisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use optim for this, avoiding to mention the interval. You can tailor the seed by taking the maximum of the function on the original guessed interval:

```
guessedInterval = min(Dvec):max(Dvec)
superStarSeed   = guessedInterval[which.max(g(guessedInterval))]

optim(par=superStarSeed, fn=function(y) -g(y))

#$par
#[1] 3

#$value
#[1] -0.3989423

#$counts
#function gradient 
#      24       NA 

#$convergence
#[1] 0

#$message
#NULL
```

Comment: Thanks @Colonel Beauvel! One question though. The user may input a domain of c(-Inf, Inf). In my case I will map Inf to the numerical value 1e64 for example. This would cause memory issues with the above approach right?

Comment: Reduce this to `-100000:100000` even if I do not know the order of magnitude of your function. Letting the user the choice of the interval is really random so you cant expect to manage all cases.

Comment: Thanks @Colonel Beauvel will try that